# Run shell script from crontab after server stop/start/restart

Tags: shell, shell-script, cron

I want to schedule a shell script in crontab that runs whenever server restarts. It should also run when someone starts the server after it stops abruptly or crashes.

How to do so in crontab? Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: If you want to start it as a startup program, you can configure it in /etc/init.d/. Or do you only need it as a crontab?

Answer (score 4):

Can you clarify what you are asking ? But to have cron run at restart you could use @reboot.

man 5 crontab

```
These special time specification "nicknames" are supported, which replace the 5 initial  time  and  date
       fields, and are prefixed by the ’@’ character:
       @reboot    :    Run once after reboot.
       @yearly    :    Run once a year, ie.  "0 0 1 1 *".
       @annually  :    Run once a year, ie.  "0 0 1 1 *".
       @monthly   :    Run once a month, ie. "0 0 1 * *".
       @weekly    :    Run once a week, ie.  "0 0 * * 0".
       @daily     :    Run once a day, ie.   "0 0 * * *".
       @hourly    :    Run once an hour, ie. "0 * * * *".
```